# Uploading IOS app to Testflight "get-task-allow must be set to true" I have tried everything

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoapods, testflight

I have an IOS app that has been working fine with testflight. I made some changes to the app and tried to upload it to testflight as I had done before but testflight gives me an error "Invalid Profile: developer build entitlements must have get-task-allow set to true".

I have researched the problem and tried many of the suggested fixes.
I have restarted XCode and rebooted the computer.
I have checked the code signing properties for the app and tried several different settings.
I have revoked all of my apple certificates and created new ones.

The update I have done since my last successful upload to testflight was update the facebook SDK and use cocoapods with my app. Is this a problem with cocoapods? Do I need to set permissions for the pods?

I have been at this for 8 hours and I am no closer to figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to the issue you've encountered:
http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/1530775-mismatched-get-task-allow-value

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried this and it did not work for me. I entered the command suggested "codesign --entitlements=- -d -vvvv <path to the app file>/AppName.app" I tried this command on my IPA file and the response was "code object is not signed at all". I used the link to send my question and IPA file to Testflight.